# Alt + F (and other mnemonics) opens appmenu locally instead of globally

Tags: shortcut-keys, 13.10, appmenu

When I press Alt + F, Alt + E, or other mnemonic, the application menu is opened locally instead of globally. That seems to happen only on native gtk applications, because in Firefox and Thunderbird I don't have this problem. See:

[image: menu mnemonic]

I didn't have that problem back in 13.04. Is this a 13.10 bug?